# Permission error in Binutil while "make install"

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, makefile, binutils, linux-from-scratch

I'm working on LFS7.2. I'm getting permission error while "make install" the binutil package, but I could successfully able to create folder in all the 3 dir (source,tools,usr) with the user lfs. I rollback and reperformed the chaper 4.1 to 4.4, but I'm still facing the issue.

**

```
lfs@logun-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build'
/bin/sh ../binutils-2.22/mkinstalldirs /tools--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs--with-lib-path=/tools/lib--target=i686-lfs-linux-gnu /tools--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs--with-lib-path=/tools/lib--target=i686-lfs-linux-gnu
mkdir -p -- /tools--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs--with-lib-path=/tools/lib--target=i686-lfs-linux-gnu /tools--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs--with-lib-path=/tools/lib--target=i686-lfs-linux-gnu
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tools--with-sysroot=': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tools--with-sysroot=': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [installdirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build'
make: *** [install] Error 2
lfs@logun-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build$
```

**

Comment: did you forget to include spaces between the options during `./configure`? `/tools--with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs--with-lib-path=/tools/lib--target=i686-lfs-linux-gnu` shouldn't be a single string...

Comment: @mata I included the space, as specified in the page 36(LFS-7.2) for configuring the binutils.

Answer (score 0):

I tried building LFS v6.3 using the live CD and encountered exactly the same problem. I think the issue is that in Chapter 5 the manual assumes your tools directory will be /tools but in the previous chapter you were told to configure your build environment to use $LFS/tools (which maps to /mnt/lfs/tools and is not the same as /tools of course). This isn't clear because everything up until that chapter has been a walkthrough telling you exactly which commands to type, then from Chapter 5 some crucial steps are missing and different assumptions appear to have been made about the build environment, or perhaps whoever wrote Chapter 5 did so without reference to the earlier chapters.